# Python compiling problems with py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe

Trying to compile a Python 2.7 script with `py2exe`, I found this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "OH_T_1.py", line 28, in <module>
File "GUI_main_1.pyc", line 6, in <module>
File "OH_T_1.pyc", line 29, in <module>
File "export_BD_spatialite_OH_T.pyc", line 13, in <module>
File "pyspatialite\dbapi2.pyc", line 27, in <module>
File "pyspatialite\_spatialite.pyc", line 12, in <module>
File "pyspatialite\_spatialite.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: La procédure spécifiée est introuvable.
```

`in_load` signifies that the compilator failed to found a `DLL` but which one ? Any help/information will be helpful.

PS: this issue is related to one I already posted : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73274/problems-with-py2exe-shapely-and-fiona

EDIT 1

More informations, my build.py (i.e `setup.py`)

```
from distutils.core import setup 
import py2exe
import matplotlib


opts = {'py2exe':{"bundle_files":3,
              "includes":["matplotlib",
                          "numpy",
                          "sip",
                          "PyQt4.QtCore",
                          "PyQt4.QtGui",
                          "osgeo",
                          "ctypes",
                          "os",
                          "sys",
                          "matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg",
                          "pyspatialite"],
              "excludes":['_gtkagg', '_tkagg', '_agg2', 
                        '_cairo', '_cocoaagg',
                        '_fltkagg', '_gtk', '_gtkcairo', ],
              'dll_excludes': ['libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll',
                               'libgobject-2.0-0.dll',
                               'mswsock.dll',
                               'powrprof.dll'],
                  'packages':["win32api","pyspatialite"]
              }
    }

setup(name='Application OH_FET',
      version='1.0',
      windows=["OH_T_1.py"],
      data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),
      options=opts,
      zipfile=None
      )
```

Comment: Don't know if the error output is relevant, but perhaps translate it to English?

Comment: I assume tho, that you've placed pyspatialite (sqlite module?) directly under your project, and you somewhere have a `imoprt pyspatialite` and it will try to upon importing load a dll as it's driver for whatever reason. This in turn can cause issues if you don't stand in the correct folder when executing `python build.py py2exe` (your build command, which you haven't posted anything about. For instance your current directory vs projects directory, your includes, exludes etc).

Comment: @Torxed, you're right, I have a `from pyspatialite import dbapi2 as db`. When I execute `setup.py` I'm in the same folder as 'OH_T_1' (my prog).

Comment: What does line 10 in `pyspatialite\_spatialite.pyc` say (and perhaps relevant information above if not just random import stuff)?

Comment: I don't know what `pyspatialite\_spatialite.pyc` says because it's a compiled version... I will try to go further, looking for environments (my prog works with IDLE,but not with Py2exe), factorisation (there's maybe a problem with a circular reference), versionning (32/64 bits, Python 2.7.A/2.7.2), etc. Say me good luck !